# Why header("Location: home.php"); is not working?

Tags: php

Why `header("Location: home.php");` is not working? My code is :

```
$press=$_GET['sell'];
 echo $press;
 if(isset($press) == SELL)
 {
    header("Location: home.php");
 }
```

Comment: is it giving any error?

Comment: did you checked whether the if condition is satisfying or not?

Comment: Cannot redirect after output to screen and you have echo $press before the redirect.

Comment: why are you posting same question again and again ?

Comment: was `SELL` a contant ?

Answer (score 0):

dont echo anything befor `header()`
It is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is sent (In PHP 4 and later, you can use output buffering to solve this problem):

for a testing try out this:

```
$press=$_GET['sell'];
 //echo $press;   i commented this
 if(isset($press) == SELL)
 {
    header("Location: home.php");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$press=$_GET['sell'];
 echo $press;
 if(isset($press) == 'SELL')
 {
    header("Location: home.php");
 }
```

Comment: `SELL` could be a constant.